# Node Knex insert not executing

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm executing this knee query in node:

```
return Knex.transaction(function (tx) {
        debug("Inserting new story record");
        return tx.insert({
            'projectId':projectId,
            'title': title,
            'story': text,
            'points': 0,
            'storyNumber': Knex('story').max('storyNumber').where('projectId', projectId)
        }, 'id')
            .into('story')
            .then(function (id) {
                debug("Returning story for %s", id);
                return getStory(id);
            })
    })
```

But the 'then()' function is never called. Anyone know why?

I've been reading all the knex doco and it appears that I've done everything right. The debug for the command looked like this:

```
crux:db Inserting new story record +4ms
{ method: 'insert',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 0, 2, 'test', 2, 'title' ],
  __knexQueryUid: 'aa5ff1d3-eff0-4687-864b-772c26e1aebd',
  sql: 'insert into `story` (`points`, `projectId`, `story`, `storyNumber`, `title`) values (?, ?, ?, (select max(`storyNumber`) from `story` where `projectId` = ?), ?)' }
```

So it all looks good to me. Just never executes.

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed... It is possible that you are just never triggering the transaction. Transaction will not be executed until `.then` is called or it is tried to be resolved in promise chain (QueryBuilder and Transaction are something that Promise A+ spec calls `thenables`https://promisesaplus.com 1.2).

Other possibility is that insert throws an error and everything is rolled back and .then will be never called.

Try this one which handles some error cases and might help you to find out real reason:

```
return Knex.transaction(function (tx) {
  debug("Inserting new story record");
  return tx.insert({
    'projectId':projectId,
    'title': title,
    'story': text,
    'points': 0,
    'storyNumber': Knex('story').max('storyNumber').where('projectId', projectId)
  })
  .into('story')
  .then(function (id) {
    debug("Returning story for %s", id);
    return getStory(id);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    debug("Insert failed", err);
    throw err;
  })
})
// just to make sure that transaction is triggered (in your code caller is responsible of that)
.then(function (blah) { return blah; }); 
.catch(function (err) { debug("Huh! Transaction failed!", err); throw err; });
```

Also in .insert({...}, returning) you seem to use mysql which doesn't support passing returning argument. So I dropped it from my suggestion...